# LangChain, terminating a chain on specific tool output

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

Im using a conversational agent, with some tools, one of them is a calculator tool (for the sake of example).

Agent initializated as follows:

```py
conversational_agent = initialize_agent(
        agent='chat-conversational-react-description',
        tools=[CalculatorTool()],
        llm=llm_gpt4,
        verbose=True,
        max_iterations=2,
        early_stopping_method="generate",
        memory=memory,
        # agent_kwargs=dict(output_parser=output_parser),
    )
```

When the `CalculatorTool` is being activated, it will return a string output, the agent takes that output and process it further to get to the "Final Answer" thus changing the formatting of the output from the `CalculatorTool`

For example, for input `10*10`, the tool `run()` function will return `100`, which will be propagated back to the agent, that will call `self._take_next_step()` and continue processing the output.

It will create a final output similar `the result of your prompt of 10x10 is 100`

I dont want the added formatting by the LLM, just the output of `100`.

I want to break the chain when the `CalculatorTool` is done, and have it's output returned to the client as is.

I also have have tools that return serialized data, for a graph chart, having that data re-processed by next iterations of the agent will make it invalid.

Comment: Your question saved my life :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to end the chain when the a langchain `Tool` has completed running, the tool must be configured with `return_redirect` boolean flag declared in `BaseTool` to `True`

```py
class CustomTool(BaseTool):

    name = "Custom tool"
    description = "Custom tool for some task"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.return_direct = True

    def _run(self, work_order_id: str):
        raise NotImplementedError("implement run function")

    def _arun(self, radius: Union[int, float]):
        raise NotImplementedError("This tool does not support async")
```

The chain will be terminated by the `Agent` using the tool, when the tool is finished processing a given input. Returning the tool's output through `AgentFinish`.

Comment: Does that cause the chain to terminate when the tool is initialised or when the tool completes (though this tool completes with an exception)?

Comment: @Matt the chain will be terminated by the `Agent` using the tool, when the tool is finished processing a given input. returning the tool's output through `AgentFinish`

Comment: So _run would be some code (e.g. get final answer from Google or a vectorstore...) that is executed and this is the last code that is executed?

Comment: @Matt Yes, the agent would take the _run() return value and return it as is

Comment: is there anyway or field can be checked to know the agent's final output is directly from a tool or llm?